# How much R and B spectrum changes over time for LED?

Tags: light-emitting-diodes

I am trying to see if there is any data on the R and B spectrum change over time for a LED. For example after 5000 hrs of operation, there are few light which gets dull, which is mostly that the luminosity gets decreased but how much it effect the E and B spectrum changes?

Comment: What colour LED are you interested in? I suspect that you're talking about white LEDs, which normally use phosphors to convert UV (or blue) to a visible spectrum.

Comment: yup mostly white LEDs.

Comment: Ok. So the spectrum changes are due to phosphor degradation. You can learn a lot about phosphors on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor). And this article looks promising if you want more details: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236246007_Extensive_analysis_of_the_degradation_of_phosphor-converted_LEDs

Comment: thanks..  i have gone through this but it doesn't seems like there is a direct co-relation and quantifiable data which suggest that the end of Life of LED is directly related to change of color shift pattern.